# React Routing with Hooks To Pass Dynamic Prop to Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to pass a default prop to a Route with React that I want to change dynamically when I call the Route later to access the nth item of a list instead of the 0th.

The Route is declared in App.js like so:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/myurl"
  render={(props) => <MyComponent{...props} startAtStep={0} />}
/>
```

Then when I trigger that route with useHistory() I want to pass in a different number - say

```
const handleEdit = (newIndex) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    push('/myurl', { startAtStep: newIndex});
  }, 220);
};
```

This, however, does not work - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using useRouteMatch in this case I think:

```
const handleEdit = (newIndex, props) => {
  let match = useRouteMatch({
    exact: true,
    path: '/myurl'
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {match && <MyComponent {...props} startAtStep={newIndex} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The route component that should be dynamic can be wrapped with

---

```
 export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

---

Now at the component { props.locaction } holds dynamic state obj, that can be modified from the navigation caller

---

```
 <Link
    to={{
      pathname: '/',
      state: { startAtStep : n }
    }}
  >
```

---